# Pulling my own private repository from Bitbucket via Composer

Tags: git, dependencies, composer-php, bitbucket, dependency-management

I have a big library that is hosted on Bitbucket as a private repository. I use this library for a lot of projects of mine.

I am having a trouble updating my library in each project where it's used whenever I do some changes, therefore I'd like to simply put it in the `composer.json` file of each project, then use `composer update` to pull the newest version.

How do I put my private repository which is hosted on Bitbucket in a `composer.json` file without making it public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set up ssh for git: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

In your composer.json of the project where you want to require the repository add the following:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@bitbucket.org:some_name/some_repository.git",
        "reference": "develop"
    }
],
```

Then in you can simply require it:

```
"vendor/projectname": "*@dev"
```

Note that the repository you are requiring should also have its own composer.json, the name set for the package there must match the name of the package you are including (vendor/projectname in my example above).

Comment: Could you also instruct me on the last part of your answer? And from the JSON above, what is the _reference_ key? What about the _*@dev_ part?

Comment: Reference is the branch name on bitbucket. *@dev instructs composer to get the latest commit, regardless of stability settings. And what exactly is unclear about the last part of the answer? I assume you know how to set up a composer.json for the other project with the proper package naming. If not, check out https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#name :)