# Composer private Bitbucket repository cannot be found

Tags: git, ssh, composer-php

I'm trying to setup a project using private Bitbucket repositories. The application includes the core and the core will subsequently include others. The application should be able to include more in the future.

Now, I use this at work with Satis, though for myself I want to just use Bitbucket, as I think that should work. I've followed the [Set up SSH for Git](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html#SetupSSHforGit-step-4-ssh-for-git) of Bitbucket and read the manual of Composer on [Git alternatives](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#git-alternatives).

I've been trying a lot of variations on the settings, but cannot work it out.

My projects `composer.json`

```
"require": {
    "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0",
    "rkeet/yc-core": "*"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@bitbucket.org:rkeet/yc-core.git"
    }
],
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\": "module/Application/src/"
    }
}
```

The YC-core `composer.json`

```
"name": "rkeet/yc-core",
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"require": {
    "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.5.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-module": "~1.0",
    "doctrine/orm": "v2.5.*",
    "rwoverdijk/assetmanager": "1.*",
    "rkeet/yc-account": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "ghislainf/zf2-whoops": "dev-master"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@bitbucket.org:rkeet/yc-account.git"
    }
],
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "YC\\Core\\": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "./Module.php"
    ]
}
```

And lastly, the yc-account `composer.json`

```
"name": "rkeet/yc-account",
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"require": {
    "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0",
    "bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize": "~1.4",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm": "~1.0",
    "rkeet/yc-core": "*"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@bitbucket.org:rkeet/yc-core.git"
    }
],
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "YC\\Account\\": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "./Module.php"
    ]
}
```

There are some other vars in the composer objects not relevant to the repositories, such as `description`, `type`, `authors`, et cetera, I've omitted those for the possibly relevant.

Result I receive when using `composer update` command is the following:

```
?[37;41mYour requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.?[39;49m

  Problem 1
    - rkeet/yc-core dev-develop requires rkeet/yc-account * -> no matching package found.
    - rkeet/yc-core dev-master requires rkeet/yc-account * -> no matching package found.
    - rkeet/yc-core dev-develop requires rkeet/yc-account * -> no matching package found.
    - rkeet/yc-core dev-develop requires rkeet/yc-account * -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for rkeet/yc-core * -> satisfiable by rkeet/yc-core[dev-develop, dev-master].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
```

Hope one of you can help me out.

Comment: Note, also had a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37784991/pulling-my-own-private-repository-from-bitbucket-via-composer) but didn't work for me.

Comment: there is a circular dependency. you require `yc-core` which requires `yc-account` which requires `yc-core`...

Comment: Tried it without that dependency as well, though will try again and post result

Comment: Since composer already has figured out that yc-core needs yc-account your first connection to bitbucket was successfull. maybe you can try adding `{
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@bitbucket.org:rkeet/yc-account.git"
    }` to your repositories section in the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the repository for yc-account to your base package.

when it comes to resolving package repository paths, composer only uses the information stored in your root package. it will scan through the composer.json of all required packages, but the repository definition there is not used.

nevertheless you may still require private repositories, which require other private repositories, but you need to add those to the repository section in your root section as well.

one of the reason is, that otherwise your dependencies could mess around from where you are downloading other packages - which you probably do not want.

see here for further explanations [Composer won't load private repository within private repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35133269/composer-wont-load-private-repository-within-private-repository?rq=1)

and as mentioned, circular dependencies should always be avoided, it may work once installed, but even then it will break at some point and the longer you build upon it, the more work you have to clean it up.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: Hi, your answer was right, but not complete. If you could update your answer with what's in your link (per @FrankerZ suggestion) and include that dependencies may still be included in private repositories (so long as they're registered with Packagist) when they're included in the project itself, I'll accept your answer ;)